# date format automatically changed from 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

so i have this javascript function:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

function CompareDates(id)
{

var monName = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

var d = new Date(id);

var curr_date = d.getDate();

var curr_month = d.getMonth();

var curr_year = d.getFullYear();


return (curr_date + " " + monName[curr_month] + " " + curr_year);
}

</script>
```

and then this calendar tag:

```
<p:calendar

id="testDate"

styleClass="calendar" 

pattern="d MMM, yyyy"

maxlength="10"

onchange="$(this).val(CompareDates($(this).val()))"

onfocus="$(this).mask('99/99/9999');"

>

<p:watermark for="testDate" value="mm/dd/yyyy" />

</p:calendar>
```

and for some unknown reason, the default date format that the textbox accepts is in **'mm/dd/yyyy'**

For example if i entered **"13-05-2014"** then it would return an error stating date is *invalid.*

If i entered **"12-05-2014"** then it would return **"5 Dec, 2014"**

I did not declare any dateformat anywhre except for the datepickers which as shown above, is **'d MMM, yyyy'**

Before this happened i trialed and error many different kind of codes to try to validate the date however it all didnt work and so i reverted it all back to the original codes.

Last time the dateformat that the textbox accepted was **'dd/mm/yyyy'** and it worked fine with my javascript function except the validation part.

Now it still works except that the dateformat changed to **'mm/dd/yyyy'**.

I did try to use console.log to find out what's wrong but there were no error messages.

So could anyone tell me and tell me what is going on here?

Why has the dateformat changed by itself?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the fact that you worte `<p:watermark for="testDate" value="mm/dd/yyyy" />` related ?

Comment: An "unknown reason [you] don't know why"? If you knew why, it wouldn't be an unknown reason you didn't know, would it? :p

Comment: btw, you can do `<input type="date">` - in supporting browsers, it lets the user pick a date in the format that their computer is set to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for correcting my language error and unfortunately i am not able to change my calendar tag :) @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: Hi @Ploutox, that watermark has no function to it :) i changed it to 'mm/dd/yyyy' to remind myself of the change in the dateformat while i was trying to fix other parts of the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
var d = new Date(id);
```

you are effectively calling [*date.parse*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2), which is largely implementation dependent. Unfortunately the default parser in most browsers expects strings in a format like nn/nn/nnnn to be month/day/year.

You can avoid that by manually parsing the string. If your string is d/m/y then:

```
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
}
```

You should also provide an on screen tip to tell users what format to use.

Comment: Hi! Yeap, my 'on screen tip' is the watermark and yeah when i have fixed this problem i will change the watermark, i left it at 'mm/dd/yyyy' as a reminder for myself as i have other errors i had to work on. :( 
And could you kindly integrate the above into my codes so i could better understand how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Hi! I replaced your codes with mine and it works! i don't need the arrays anymore! However i need the format to be **d, MMM yyyy** so may i know how can i alter the above to make it that way? right now it prints 'day month date year hr:min:ss'