# How to convert date to a custom format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

How do i convert a date of the format `dd/MM/yyyy (eg:29/04/2016)` to the format `ddd,MMM yyyy (eg: Fri, 29 Apr 2016)`?

Comment: Take a look of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Hint: Do a search first, then show your effort with the code you tried

Comment: Since it was just a few days ago I wrote a new script, here you are as a welcome present: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/u0sux9d2/

Comment: @mplungjan thank you this was i looking for :)'

Comment: @mplungjan—that question is not a full duplicate of this one. The OP has a string, not a Date, so it is not just about formatting a date string from a date.

Comment: Before you can use mplungjan's code you must first convert your string to a Date. See the answer [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078497/date-format-automatically-changed-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy/24078641#24078641).

Comment: @RobG  take a closer look at my fiddle - I have `var inp = "29/04/2016".split("/");` - I even use European format as OP did. There is only room for one duplicate and string splitting is another question

Comment: @mplungjan—cool, I don't know why you call it "European format", it's used far more widely than that and isn't the only format used in Europe.

Comment: As opposed to the "native us" format assumed by JS. mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy